# Issue while checking pattern with regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I've got a problem while checking manually if my inputs are matching my patterns

Here is the function I use to check it

```
if (!$element.attr("pattern")) return true;

    let pattern = $element.attr("pattern");
    let exp;
    if (pattern.charAt(0) === "^") exp = new RegExp(pattern);
    else exp = new RegExp('^' + pattern + '$');

    if (exp.test($element.val())) return true;
    else {
        return false;
    }
```

I've checked without my ifelse which I use to set the var "exp", but the result is the same.

Here is the input I want to check

```
<input class="k-textbox cyclique-input-popin" type="text" pattern="^[0-9]+([,][0-9])?$"/>
```

It has a value of 0,25, and I want it to be abble to have value like that :

- 1,25
- 1,2
- 0,2
- 20
- ...

Can have a "," or not, but can't have trailing zeros like 1,20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Trailing zeros are permitted by your current pattern, and (2) the pattern only allows one digit to the right of the comma. You want something like this:

```html
<input ... pattern="^[0-9]+(,[0-9]*[^0])?$">
```

Finally, your code can be simplified some:

```js
let pattern = $element.attr('pattern');
if (!pattern) {
  return true;
}

let exp;
if (pattern[0] === '^') {
  exp = new RegExp(pattern);
} else {
  exp = new RegExp('^' + pattern + '$');
}

return exp.test($element.val()));
```

Let me know whether that gets you the result you're looking for. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, it matchs perfectly what I want.